# Vaadin Autocomplete with Google places autocomplete API

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I would like directions on how to implement a google places with vaadin `textfield` i already looked it up that its best to implement with the `combo-box` component.

[image]

Comment: Please expand your question. Its meaning is not entirely clear.
I'm have experience with google places service. But I don't understand what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

i was able to acheive this easily using this plugin from the vaadin directory [paper-input-place-component](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/paper-input-place-component)